# Java local variables and frequently called methods

Tags: java, memory-management, local-variables

if I call a method at acertain rate (less than 10 secs) and this method write some stuff in a file. Now if this method uses a Date object to format the stuff it writes, should I consider to declare the Date objects as an instance variable (thus skipping allocation and deallocations) to improve performance? Or is it insignificant?

Comment: Would your `Date` object be valid in the next invocation? Do you maybe mean `DateFormat`?

Comment: Actually, if the JVM can prove that the Date object only exists for the duration of your method, then it is faster for it to be local. Either way, it is insignificant - code for readability and maintainability, and only optimize once performance is actually an issue.

Comment: @dragan-bozanovic Yes if I update it with `date.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis())`